# Running Oozie Action on a future date

Tags: oozie, oozie-coordinator, oozie-workflow

I have a requirement for which a workflow is on demand run.But there is a task ( curl command) to  get triggered at a future time .

Answer (score 0):

You can use [coordinator jobs](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/5.2.0/CoordinatorFunctionalSpec.html) to schedule your workflows.

The are tons of option, but the most important thing is the following part of the `coordinator.xml` where you can specify your start and end date:

```
<coordinator-app name="[NAME]" frequency="[FREQUENCY]"
     start="[DATETIME]" end="[DATETIME]" timezone="[TIMEZONE]"
     xmlns="uri:oozie:coordinator:0.1">
...
```

Checking the `cron-schedule` example of Oozie might also help: https://github.com/apache/oozie/tree/release-5.2.0/examples/src/main/apps/cron-schedule